# Find the locus of mid points of the chord to a circle passing through a point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, locus

Find the locus of mid points of the chord to the circle  $(x-3)^2 + (y-2)^2 =1$ passing through the point $(3,7)$.

I have a doubt , the point $(3,7)$ lies outside the circle isn't? What does passing through the point $(3,7)$ mean? Sorry if I am wrong. Just give me clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M(x,y)$ one of points on the locus, $A(3,7)$ and $B(3,2)$ be a center of the circle.

Thus, since $BM\perp MA$, we see that our locus is placed on the circle:
$$\left(x-\frac{3+3}{3}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{7+2}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{AB}{2}\right)^2$$ or
$$(x-3)^2+(y-4.5)^2=6.25$$

Comment: Just procedure is more than enough, I will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, but still the point (3,7) lies outside the circle. What does the point mean?

Comment: I understood the question thank you

Comment: @Siva Sankar Sajeev You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

We know that,.   Given passing point and centre of the given circle are ends of diameter therefore                                     centre of the circle is mid-point of those end points and radius is half of the distance between those end points.        The equation of circle is   (x-3)^2+(y-4.5)^2=6.25